# Unknown encoder 'libfaac'

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I'm using [carrierwave-video](https://github.com/rheaton/carrierwave-video) to upload video with my ruby on rails app. But I have this problem when try encode the video:

```
Unknown encoder 'libfaac'

Errors: no output file created.
```

I have tried with:

```
sudo apt-get install libfaac-dev
```

but I get the same error.

**Updated**:

After compile ffmpeg, I get the same error:

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2011-10-13 18:54:50
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.5 2011010300
  Duration: 00:06:43.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 380 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:5], 279 kb/s, 9.25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-10-13 18:54:50
      handler_name    : 
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 97 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2011-10-13 18:54:50
      handler_name    : 
Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
Unknown encoder 'libfaac'

Errors: no output file created.
```

Comment: Were you able to make this work with carrierwave-video?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

[FFmpeg removed libfaac support](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?a=commit;h=dc0f711459e0c682bf9f94ba38d26736e90cff45) in 2016 because the other AAC encoders are better. Use a different encoder.

## Native FFmpeg AAC Encoder (`-c:a aac`)

Use the native, built-in FFmpeg AAC encoder:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a aac output.m4a
```

- Included by default in all `ffmpeg` versions.
- Has many features, fairly good quality, supports the most channel layouts and sample rates.
- See more details and specific options with `ffmpeg -h encoder=aac`.

## Fraunhofer FDK AAC Encoder (`-c:a libfdk_aac`)

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a libfdk_aac output.m4a
```

- Provides excellent quality.
- Supports HE-AAC.
- Not compatible with the GPL, and therefore not often made available by distributors, so you'll need to [compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) to use it.
- See more details and specific options with `ffmpeg -h encoder=libfdk_aac`.

## Apple AudioToolbox AAC (`-c:a aac_at`)

- Only available for macOS/iOS users.
- See more details and specific options with `ffmpeg -h encoder=aac_at`.

## Microsoft Media Foundation AAC (`-c:a aac_mf`)

- Only available for Windows users with `ffmpeg` compiled with `--enable-mediafoundation`.
- See more details and specific options with `ffmpeg -h encoder=aac_mf`.

#### Also see:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)

Comment: I have compiled ffmpeg and I have the same result: The ouput is the same result. Thanks! I have updated the question after compile ffmpeg

Comment: @hyperrjas The guide does not explicitly enable libfaac. You have to add that by installing **libfaac-dev** package and then adding `--enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree` to the ffmpeg configure. Sorry, I was not clear about that. Why can you not use libfdk_aac instead of libfaac?

Comment: Are there any other inbuilt AAC encoders in ubuntu that you can use without compiling ffmpeg?

Comment: @cp101020304 You can use the native FFmpeg AAC encoder (option 2). There have been some recent development and improvements to it lately. You can [download a recent static build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) to take advantage of that. Or you can pipe to a standalone encoder such as `faac` (option 3).

Answer (score 2):

hopefully this helps :

Download medibuntu repository list:
Code:

> sudo wget http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/`lsb_release
>   -cs`.list --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list && sudo apt-get -q update && sudo apt-get --yes -q
>   --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get -q update

Grab the extras with restricted codecs:
Code:

> sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-52

Comment: Medibuntu no longer provides any packages. See the [announcement](https://launchpad.net/medibuntu/+announcement/11951).

Comment: Ohh...didnt knew that