# PHP-FFMpeg video output is truncated

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm using the PHP-FFMpeg library found [here](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) and code from the "[Basic Usage](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#basic-usage)" section.

The outputted video seems to be truncated. I'm using a source video that's 28 seconds long, but the output is only 9 seconds. What's going wrong?

Here, I'm checking the duration of the source video:

```
$ffprobe = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create();
$duration = $ffprobe
  ->format('test/source.mp4')
  ->get('duration');
```

> 28.700000

Then generating an output video:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('test/source.mp4');
$video->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'test/export.mp4');
```

Then checking the duration of the output video:

```
$ffprobe = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create();
$duration = $ffprobe
  ->format('test/export.mp4')
  ->get('duration');
```

> 9.234000

Comment: Please show the entire console log output from the actual ffmpeg conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [slhck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435093/slhck) for the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729861/php-ffmpeg-video-output-is-truncated#comment100023232_56729861) to investigate the conversion log.
It seems that my source file was corrupt.
I documented my process below.

---

I'm not aware of a way to get the ffmpeg output from the PHP-FFMpeg library.
So I used [`getFinalCommand()`](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/pull/441) to output the ffmpeg command:

```
$video = $ffmpeg->open('test/source.mp4');
echo $video->getFinalCommand(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'test/export.mp4')[0];
```

> -y -i test/source.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -b:v 1000k -refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1 -b:a 128k -pass 1 -passlogfile /tmp/ffmpeg-passes5d108f0d5007cirj2x/pass-5d108f0d500f9 test/export.mp4

I executed the command got this error:

> [libx264 @ 0x2395ec0] ratecontrol_init: can't open stats file
>   Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream
>   #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

The `passlogfile` seemed to be causing problems, so I removed it and got:

> corrupt input packet in stream 0:04.76 bitrate= 880.0kbits/s speed=3.15x
>   [h264 @ 0x7b4500] Invalid NAL unit size (51618 > 33287).
>   [h264 @ 0x7b4500] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
>   Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input

It seems that my source video file was corrupt.
I reuploaded it and the error was gone.

---

In the process, I also found that "audio codec libfaac has been [removed](http://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?a=commit;h=dc0f711459e0c682bf9f94ba38d26736e90cff45) from ffmpeg" ([iki789](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/539#issuecomment-394149853)), that "there are better alternatives" ([llogan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777823/924299)), and that the audio codec can be set to "aac" like this:

```
$format = new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
$format->setAudioCodec("aac");

$video = $ffmpeg->open('test/source.mp4');
$video->save($format, 'test/export.mp4');
```

Comment: Is PHP-FFMpeg (not sure why they decided to misspell FFmpeg) adding all of those unnecessary x264 encoding options? You can remove `-refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1` because the [x264 presets](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Preset) deal with all of those.

Comment: @llogan Yes, I assume so. I'm not very familiar with the library's code, but [this section seems relevant](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/src/FFMpeg/Media/AbstractVideo.php#L160).