# FFmpeg - change audio codec

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, ffmpeg-php

Here is my code:

```
$format = new X264('aac', 'libx264');
$format->setKiloBitrate(500);
```

but when videos transcode with `pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg`, this package sets audio codec to `mp3` by default instead `aac`.

How solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that your FFMPEG built with `libfaac`?

Comment: Unknown encoder 'libfaac'

Answer (score 0):

I told you about the `libfaac` encoder. But I figured out this one was deprecated in 2016. Because there are other better encoders out there such as `aac`, `libfdk_aac`, `aac_at` etc. Check out more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777823).

You should first check those encoders out on your command line tool to make sure your ffmpeg was compiled with those encoders. Let's use `aac` encoder because it is included by default in all ffmpeg versions.

```
ffmpeg -i real_audio.mp3 -c:a aac converted_audio.aac
```

I used the `laravel-ffmpeg` with `aac` encoder to convert `mp3` to `aac`. It worked like a charm. See the following code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264;
use ProtoneMedia\LaravelFFMpeg\Support\FFMpeg;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {
        echo "<p>Converting...</p>";

        FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')
            ->open('audio.mp3')
            ->export()
            ->toDisk('public')
            ->inFormat(new X264('aac'))
            ->save('converted_audio.aac');
    }
}
```

To know more about `aac` encoder use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -h encoder=aac
```

My `laravel-ffmpeg` package version is

```
"pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg": "^7.0"
```

and ffmpeg version is

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.6
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: tnx for answer, i use aac same as you, but when pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg transcodes video, audio codec change to libmp3lame by default.problem is here!

Comment: No! I tried both video mp4 to audio aac and audio mp3 to audio aac and both work fine. It may happens because libfaac is deprecated now, and X264 takes libfaac as default audio codec, (I'm not sure) it may be a fallback to libmp3lame. So you need to specify the codec while converting audio to video and vice versa.

Comment: my code works on local very well but when using that on server change audio format to libmp3lame by default!!!

Comment: That's why I told you to check out whether or not one of `aac`, `libfdk_aac`, `aac_at` etc. codec is installed (on your server). Therefore, is `FFMPEG` complied with the codec that you need? Check `FFMPEG`'s version. New versions of it get compiled with `aac` codec by default. If it's not possible digging into your server, then ask hosting provider about that.

Comment: i am using laravel 5.8 in my project and last version of pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg compatible with that is 4.0

Comment: The version `pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg` of it is not important here but the version of `ffmpeg` on your server. Because you've to figure out (to know why it's being fallback to `libmp3lame`) with what codes the `ffmpeg` compiled on your server.

Comment: ffmpeg version 4.2.2 on server

Comment: Well, then it should be OK. Can you share your code via pastebin.com or something else?

Comment: https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/issues/205

Comment: Your code seems quite OK to me but one thing is the version of `pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg`. Why is its version 4.0 as your `ffmpeg`'s version is 4.2.2? Are you able to check codecs/formats on your server? If so, try `ffmpeg -formats` or `ffmpeg -codecs`. It may help you.

Comment: because i used laravel 5.8 in my project and latest version is 4.0.ffmpeg - formats and -codecs is ok